# How many RMI Server connections can A JAVA application as "RMI client" make?

Tags: java, rmi

Please assume that, there are 2500 RMI servers, and 1 java application is connecting these servers as RMI client. In this case, what is the maximum allowed Remote Server Connection Count for JAVA client Application(RMI client. )

Can this single java application connect simultaneously 2500 Servers. Different ip addresses remote public and the same port.

Comment: There is no specific maximum. It's up to operating system limits, memory, threads, file descriptors, etc. I had software in a system that had 50,000 remote objects 15 or more years ago, so I don't think you're anywhere near a limit.

Comment: You should also be aware of RMI client-side connection pooling and server-side port sharing. It's entirely possible that you will only use one connection.